# Rails AJAX not working over HTTPS, generating 302 error, can you see what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the following javascript / AJAX function which is embedded on our payment page, it is meant to check if the user has made payment every 5 seconds and if they have redirect them to a confirmation page.

This code works fine on our development box, which does not have HTTPS, but on our production server firebug tells me that a 302 error occurs when the javascript is called.

When I copy the URL generated / used by the AJAX and paste it into my browser, the expected json is returned.

Can anyone see what is wrong here?

> ```
>         function check_payment() {
>          jQuery.ajax({
>            url: "/ads/check_payment/<%= @ad.id %>", 
>            dataType: 'json',
>            tyle: "POST",
>            error: function(xhr_data) {
>              // terminate
>            },
>          success: function(xhr_data) {
>            if (xhr_data.status == 'pending') {
>              setTimeout(function() { check_for_payment(); }, 5000);
>            } else {
>              window.location.replace("/confirmation")
>            }
>          },
>          contentType: 'application/json'
>          });
>        }
>        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
>          check_payment();
>       });
> ```

Comment: Check if both your page with javascript and server side script have https.

Answer (score 3):

Got this fixed, there where two problems:

1. AJAX request was not being sent to the server over HTTPS
2. I had to add the following line to the top of my controller

> ssl_required :check_payment

Everything worked fine then, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've got some 302 errors when I tried to do a cross domain ajax request. If the https is in cause (even if I don't think), try to read the doc about the jsonp dataType : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax